# Laravel - using inRandomOrder() on belongsToMany RelationShips

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

in this code as:

```
$latestHerbsInformation = \App\ContentCategories::find('14')->contents->take(5);
```

which that work fine i want to use `inRandomOrder()` to get random rows from contents, `Contents` and `ContentCategories` are `belongsToMany RelationShips` and this code:

```
$latestHerbsInformation = \App\ContentCategories::find('14')->contents->inRandomOrder()->take(5);
```

don't work for me.

`Contents` model:

```
class Contents extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;
    protected $table = 'contents';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ContentCategories::class);
    }
}
```

`ContentCategories` model:

```
class ContentCategories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contents_categories';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function contents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Contents::class);
    }
}
```

i get this error:

```
Method inRandomOrder does not exist.
```

how can i solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct query is:

```
\App\ContentCategories::find('14')->contents()->inRandomOrder()->take(5)->get();
```

Because this will execute the query and will return a collection:

```
\App\ContentCategories::find('14')->contents
```

Comment: hi Alexey :) you save my time again Thanks